# change of language for the text taken from xml file ,in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, multilingual

I  have done a feedback taking app , where im taking the questions from a xml file.Now i need to change the language with respect to the language selected on the device.Should i translate it manually or is there any way
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have localized strings in your project if it is static questions.
Else, if you getting the questions from server thru XML, then you ask the server to send the questions in the required language. You can get the current language selection using NSLocale.

```
NSString * languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```